# How do I stop and start a loop in QT?

Tags: c++, qt

I've been trying to figure out how to make the program stop in a for-loop and wait for a button to be clicked and the for-loop continues.

Isn't there any easy way to stop the loop like `QSystem.stop()` and in the button clicked function `QSystem.star()` and the loop continues.

In C++ you could use `system("pause")` or the program stopped when you used a `cin<<`. But how do i do this in QT?

Comment: To the downvoter. This is a good question. OP did not understand about the semantics of event based programming. A perfectly valid question to ask.

Comment: Just in case: do you know what is a debugger? Do you know how to use it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the userinterface needs its code to run, if you halt event loop (which also means that any function that gets called from within the event loop is blocking, waiting for some event), you also halt the user interface, which means clicks into the window won't be processed. That's why in event based programming, which is what *all* UI kits do, it is essential to return to the main event handler loop as quickly as possible.

What you can do is create a second thread and wait on a condition variable. The GUI thread can signal that condition variable in the button click event slot.

> In C++ you could use system("pause") or the program stopped

Exactly: The program is stopped. Which means it won't fetch *events* from the operating system. However receiving data from stdin is not an event. It's blocking on streamed I/O. Graphical user interfaces are event based though.

Note that conceptually it's not really impossible to think of a user interface to provide streaming I/O channels. However that doesn't work in single threaded programs. You need parallel execution (coroutines, threads, or such) for a concept like this to work.

Comment: Thank you datenwolf this helped med a lot :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need threads, nested event loop will do the job.

```
int waitUntilSignalIsEmitted(QObject *sender, const char *signal) {
    QEventLoop loop;
    connect(sender, signal,
            &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    return loop.exec();
}

// usage:
while(yourLoopCondition) {
   // some stuff
   ...
   // pause here
   waitUntilSignalIsEmitted(yourContinuationButton, SIGNAL(clicked()));

   // loop continuation
   ...
}
```

Comment: Of course a nested event loop is an evil that's best avoided, since it leads to bugs that can be very hard to pin down. Your code is an excellent example that finds use in porting from other toolkits to Qt, though.

Comment: I never had a problems with that, but I've never overused it. Anyway for newbie it is much better and safer them playing around with threads.

Comment: I think that pedagogically a newbie should really learn about asynchronous coding and how to use zero-length timers. Then the thread issue is not a problem: one can move the object to a new thread if/when convenient.

Comment: Most probably you are right. I'm pretty sure that he asked question incorrectly. I mean that he has some simple problem, which he tries to solve in this strange way, so he ask us to fix his solution, instead explaining the real problem. I wouldn't be surprised if debugger is the thing he really needs.